# Send image from Google Glass to Android phone

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I would like to create an app that will show image captured from Google glass.
After I take a picture on glass I want do some image filtering on my device and show the image on some activity, after the application will send result Ok\fail back to glass.
Can It possible to create some client\server app with glass,
maybe a service on the phone that will receive the image and run activity that will send result back to glass?

code samples will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have noted that using the Google Mirror API to create your application is not an option for you. (There is even a sample application "add a cat to that" that will do this ([here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/stories#add_a_cat_to_that)).  That sample application receives a picture, adds a cat to the picture on the server side, and returns the adjusted picture to Google Glass.)

Currently direct communication between Glass and your phone (Android or IPhone) is not supported (see requested enhancement [issue 272](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=272&q=phone&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) here).

That leaves you with one design pattern available - communication through the cloud. You  would need to use the Glass Developers Kit, take the picture and post to a server "in the cloud"; while your Phone app would need to be monitoring server for a new picture (or use server side code to trigger an alert to your phones application).

Comment: I want to do image manipulation on the device,and I have an Android app that doing special image manipulation on my phone. so I need to get image to my device

Comment: You may still want to consider re-architecting your solution and using your Java code on a Google App Engine server.  If you are trying to do this work completely offline, I don't know of a current solution pattern .. other than moving the image processing to Glass (that could shorten battery life, I guess).

Comment: I don't care doing it online and I can connect the glass to WIFI as well, is it possible to create client app on the glass with a standard http client using GDK and the server will be the phone? Thank's for your help.